# How do I install libXSLT for Perl's XML::LibXSLT?

Tags: perl, binding, libxslt

When I run a Perl script I get

```
    Can't locate XML/LibXSLT.pm in @INC
```

So I try doing this in `cpan`:

```
cpan> install XML::LibXSLT
CPAN: Storable loaded ok
Going to read /root/.cpan/Metadata
  Database was generated on Fri, 02 Oct 2009 13:28:24 GMT
Running install for module XML::LibXSLT
Running make for P/PA/PAJAS/XML-LibXSLT-1.68.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::MD5 loaded ok
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/P/PA/PAJAS/XML-LibXSLT-1.68.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /root/.cpan/build for sizes
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/perl-libxml-mm.h
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/t/
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/t/08literal.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/t/09exslt.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/t/02dromeds.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/t/01basic.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/t/14security.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/t/12import.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/t/05quick.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/t/03input.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/t/13error.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/t/11utf8.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/t/04params.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/t/06entities.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/t/06output.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/t/07blankdoc.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/t/10functions.t
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/testcases/
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/testcases/default.conf
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/Changes
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/example/
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/example/1.xsl
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/example/2.xsl
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/example/fatal.xsl
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/example/nonfatal.xsl
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/example/bad1.xsl
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/example/1.xml
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/example/bad3.xsl
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/example/bad2.xsl
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/example/2.xml
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/MANIFEST
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/typemap
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/Driver/
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/Driver/LibXSLT.pm
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/Driver/Sablotron.pm
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/Driver/BaseClass.pm
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/perl-libxml-mm.c
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/LibXSLT.pm
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/benchmark.pl
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/ppport.h
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/LibXSLT.xs
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/Makefile.PL
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/README
XML-LibXSLT-1.68/META.yml
Removing previously used /root/.cpan/build/XML-LibXSLT-1.68

  CPAN.pm: Going to build P/PA/PAJAS/XML-LibXSLT-1.68.tar.gz

running xslt-config... failed
using fallback values for LIBS and INC
options:
  LIBS='-L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lxslt -lxml2 -lz -lm'
  INC='-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include'
If this is wrong, Re-run as:
  $ /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL LIBS='-L/path/to/lib' INC='-I/path/to/include'

looking for -lxslt... no
libxslt not found
Try setting LIBS and INC values on the command line
Or get libxslt and libxml2 from
  http://www.libxml.org/
If you install via RPMs, make sure you also install the -devel
RPMs, as this is where the headers (.h files) are.
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
  /usr/bin/make  -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

So... no luck. I tried writing `cpan> install XML::XSLT` which installed but my script still doesn't work. What can I do now?

I also tried using YaST to install the packages. It was a success, then I tried the above and still no luck.

-extra-

I also tried building the bindings. From http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/dist/XML-LibXSLT I untar and wrote

```
    # perl Makefile.PL
    running xslt-config... failed
    using fallback values for LIBS and INC
    options:
      LIBS='-L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lxslt -lxml2 -lz -lm'
      INC='-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include'
    If this is wrong, Re-run as:
      $ /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL LIBS='-L/path/to/lib' INC='-I/path/to/include'

    looking for -lxslt... no
    libxslt not found
    Try setting LIBS and INC values on the command line
    Or get libxslt and libxml2 from
      http://www.libxml.org/
    If you install via RPMs, make sure you also install the -devel
    RPMs, as this is where the headers (.h files) are.
```

Answer (score 14):

on ubuntu try

```
sudo apt-get install libxml-libxslt-perl
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `libxslt` library, which should be available using your OS's standard package distribution system (e.g. it's available on [macports for Darwin](http://libxslt.darwinports.com/), but you can also [download it from source here](http://xmlsoft.org/xslt/downloads.html).

This is the key part of the output that indicates this:

> looking for -lxslt... no
>   libxslt not found

EDIT: since you seem to be using OpenSUSE, you can download the library directly from here: http://www.novell.com/products/linuxpackages/opensuse/libxslt.html.

Comment: looking for -lxslt... yes
looking for -lexslt... no
I cant find exslt

Answer (score 1):

[In response to the now-merged question "I can't find exslt":]

Are you looking for a more detailed answer than [www.exslt.org](http://www.exslt.org/)?

Comment: when i DLed there was only files and no lib (xsl files IIRC)

Answer (score 0):

Install the packages `libxml2-devel` and `libxslt-devel` from YaST.